# subprocess.run() get pid of the process

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to run a program from inside my Python script and get the PID of the process I launched. I tried with :
`p=subprocess.Popen(nameofmyprocess) pid=p.pid`
But the problem is that it doesn't wait for my called program to finish. When I looked at the documentation, I concluded I should use `subprocess.run()` instead, however it doesn't have a `.pid` like `Popen`
Is there another alternative ?

**Edit :**
I should have mentioned this in the original question. The code of my program includes a server part where it opens a socket and listens to it. I have a client side which connects to that socket and sends a message. My end goal is to write a script that runs my program, gets its PID to pass it to some functions I wrote that will do the monitoring of my program : they will show me the memory usage of my program, the socket it has opened, the file descriptors.. basically information about things my program does.
As suggested , I used `subprocess.Popen.poll` so now my code looks like this :

```
p=subprocess.Popen(nameofmyprocess) 
pid=p.pid
print pid
while (p.poll() is None):
   time.sleep(20)
   myFunc(pid)
   myFunc2(pid)
```

However, when I run this script and run my client, it can't connect to my server program. It says "Connection failed". I'm pretty sure the program is running though because the PID I print is displayed when I use the command `ps aux` on another terminal.

Comment: `subprocess.Popen` has a method called `wait` that waits for the child-process to terminate, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Why do you need the PID if you wait for it to finish? Wouldn't the PID be useless at that time?

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I want to run the program and do some things on it (monitor its memory usage, check its file descriptors..) , the goal is to attach my script to the program so that when I run my script it runs the program, gets its pid and starts the monitoring using the pid.

Comment: So again, why do you need to `wait`? This blocks your program until the process finishes and you will not be able to do any monitoring...

Comment: @Tomerikoo you're right, what would be another alternative ? I'm fairly new to this so any push in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: [`subprocess.Popen.poll`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll) will check if the process has terminated, which based on your other comments here is more something you're looking for. Just have a While-loop with a small delay, and check the process at the start of each loop.

Comment: @HampusLarsson thank you so much! However, my program acts as a server and waits for a connection from a client by opening a TCP socket and listening. When I do as you said, I can see that the program is actually running (using ps aux) however my client can't connect to my program, it says "Connection failed". It does work if I run my program normally from a terminal so it doesn't have to do with my server/client code. Is there any logical explanation for this ?

Comment: @HampusLarsson I apologize, I just edited the post !

Comment: Are you sure it successfully listens? A common problem with servers is that they leave the socket reserved for a while if you terminate them or they crash, and then the new instance you start right after won't be granted access to the port they want to listen to.

Comment: @tripleee I checked and as you said it's not listening. It's weird though, why is it that when my program is called with subprocess.Popen it doesn't go into listening mode, whereas if I run it normally from a terminal everything works fine ?

Comment: I don't remember the specifics, it's probably not related to `Popen` directly but try adding the "reuse port" flag when you request the socket.

Comment: It's already there in my program code :
`if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(opt))) 
    { 
        perror("setsockopt"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } `